# Why can't Azure build find .dll files, when local build can?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-identity, web-publishing

I have built a .NET API and I am trying to publish it. It builds fine and I can run it and access it locally without any problems. But when I try to publish it to Azure it is telling me that the build fails. These are the errors I am getting from the output:

[image]

The four errors have to do with four files that end with the extension .dll when I follow the path I can see that the file exists but for some reason, I get an error that they can't be found.
Another thing I have noticed is that all four files producing the errors, Model, Identity, Repository, and Services all would have something to do with Microsoft Identity.
**Could that be it?**
I know another box in the publish screen asked me to enter the key-value pairs for my Azure database to connect to it.
**I have my JWT token key in my app settings JSON, do I need to enter those as dependencies in Azure?**
**If so how do I do that?**

Comment: I have tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it but that didn't work.

Comment: hey @Ben Crowe by any chance have you gone through this https://ninocrudele.com/error-cs0006-metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found

Comment: Also have you tried selecting the project dependencies manually by clicking the project in Solution explorer if not try that as well

Comment: let me know if the above solution works once you try it out

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am a newbie and haven't used Visual Studio a lot. I downloaded the target framework migrator from https://ninocrudele.com/error-cs0006-metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found . I dind't understand what it wanted me to do with the nuget package manager.  All of the projects had the same build configuration.  I don't understand how to:                                                                       Unload all the project from the solution and start loading each project starting from the base library. 
Every time you reload one then rebuild the solution.

Comment: Are there any blogs or tutorials that show how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246363/discussion-between-saisakethguduru-mt-and-ben-crowe).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an older version of Visual Studio. I updated VS 2019 to the current version, and it published the API to Azure. The API works great. Thank you for your help.